# How do I configure netscaler to act as a simple HTTP proxy?

Tags: http-proxy, netscaler

I want to start use a netscaler instance as a HTTP proxy (like squid), so all the requests from my browser will go directly to netscaler.

How can I obtain this behaviour?

Note: Netscaler is already configured to deal with requests coming from 80 and 443 ports on the VIP interface.

Still I do want to allow it to process any requests.

Note: if you wonder why, the primary motive is for testing purpose, it's much easier to tell people to configure a HTTP proxy inside their browser instead of modifying the hosts file in order to force few websites to use a different server.

By doing this, it would allow me to easily perform an A/B testing of the netscaler configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is here:

http://blogs.citrix.com/2010/02/25/netscaler-feature-of-the-day-deploy-as-a-forward-proxy/

It uses the cache redirection feature to process the traffic.

Comment: I wasn't able to follow the DNS part of the guide but I does work even without the DNS part. Thank you.